# Google Picker API - how to load a picker on demand

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-picker

I want to use the [google picker api](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/index) . The example shows the picker being loaded when the page loads, and I want a picker to be loaded when I click on something, but it doesn't seem to work properly in that situation. So the working example is:

```
<script>

google.setOnLoadCallback(createImgPicker);
google.load('picker', '1');

function createImgPicker(){
  //CREATE HERE
}

</script>
```

but what I want is something like:

```
$('#button').on('click',function(){
  google.setOnLoadCallback(createImgPicker);
  google.load('picker', '1');
});
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
$('#button').on('click',function(){

  google.load('picker', '1', {"callback": function (e) {

    //do stuff

  }});
});
```